# Send mail from a different domain in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I understand from the [mail documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html) that GAE is limited in who mail can come from when sent by the app.  There are options for receiving incoming mail on a different domain (basically having it forwarded) but are there any options for sending mail from an app. Ideally i'd like my app to be able to send mail from a different address for each user in my app, so that when replies were received I could match them up to the user that sent them.

I'd ideally like the emails to come from `<userid>@<custom.domain>.com` but could live with being able to send them from `<userid>@app-id.appspotmail.com`.

Do I have any options here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, your only option would be to communicate with an external server that via a URLFetch. The external server would be responsible for sending and receiving email through the usual means and providing a web service interface that your AppEngine app could use.

Comment: An external server would only have to handle sending explicitly; you could do receiving by forwarding it to the appspotmail address.